# Time Independent Schrodinger equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$-k^2f''(x)=(E^2-V(x))f(x)$
I have checked for many V(x) that the set of solutions to this differential equation are complete and have an orthogonal basis set, is this always true for all V(x)?

Comment: Complete means every square integrable function can be written as int a(k)z(k,x) dk , where z(k,x) is all solutions parametrized by k, and a(k) is allowed to be a delta function

Comment: orthogonal means int z(k,x)*z(b,x) dx vanishes when b not equal to k

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "complete and have an orthogonal basis set".  If $V(x)$ is continuous, there is always a two-dimensional vector space of solutions.  The solutions may or may not be in $L^2$ near $+\infty$ or near $-\infty$.  You might look up
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory_of_ordinary_differential_equations#Limit_circle_and_limit_point_for_singular_equations

Comment: Complete means every square integrable function can be written as int a(k)z(k,x) dk , where z(k,x) is all solutions parametrized by k, and a(k) is allowed to be a delta function

Comment: In order to use the Spectral Theorem, you want a self-adjoint operator.  For your operator to be essentially self-adjoint on $C_0^\infty$ (the smooth functions of compact support) you need $V(x)$ to be in the limit point case at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.